# Supabase Flutter Web OAuth Redirect Issue

Tags: supabase

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:spacevault_cash/constants.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'package:supabase/supabase.dart' as supabase_;

import '../services/supabase_service.dart';

class TestPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider);
    print(supabase.auth.currentSession);

    // Use the user variable here
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        ref.read(supabaseProvider).auth.signInWithOAuth(
            supabase_.Provider.github,
            redirectTo: kIsWeb ? null : authRedirectUrl);
      },
      child: Text(user != null ? 'Logged in' : 'Login'),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm having trouble authenticating users when using the web client. When clicking on the button, the user gets redirected to GitHub. After entering valid credentials, the users is sent back to the application, however `supabase.auth.currentSession` prints `null`.
However, I can see the access_token in the URL bar, so it should actually have everything it needs. Any Ideas?

Just for context: This works fine for iOS and Android

Answer (score 1):

For web authentication, it is important to not set `authCallbackUrlHostname`.
Using `null` in as the `redirectTo` is not enough if you initialize the supabase client with the `authCallbackUrlHostname`.

I had to remove the `authCallbackUrlHostname` from the following code.

```dart
  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: supabaseURL,
    anonKey: supabaseAnonKey,
    authCallbackUrlHostname: 'login-callback-url',
    debug: true,
  );
```

I actually wrote two different setups which I import by looking at what platform it is run on.

```dart
import 'configure_nonweb.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'configure_web.dart';
```